# I have an HTML doc with a bunch of links that are not formatted. Is there a way to automatically add <a> tags in the markup?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, hyperlink, atom-editor

I am using Visual Studio Code and Atom. Is there any ability to highlight the text and add a tag to it automatically?

Basically I want to generate links based on text that I have in the HTML. For example I have a bunch of different text like https://www.example.com in my HTML document without any tags..

How can I add and output 
`<a href="https://www.example.com">https://www.example.com</a>` in the editor automatically. I have text without links and I want to add links to them automatically in the editor.

Can you do this in the editor or do you have to use JavaScript and then copy and paste the output back into the editor? Should I try regexr?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the find an replace function of your editor. I am assuming you are using an editor that has this functionality.

For Visual Studio Code, this can be done by pressing `command + f` or `ctrl + f` on windows.

[image]

So you find the link, for example, I used https://stackoverflow.com and replaced it with `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link</a>`.

Nut you have to be careful doing this so as to not replace what you don't intend replacing.

Comment: Thanks, this would work, but the problem is that they are all different, so I would have to manually input each one. I'm trying to do them all at once automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any plugin that does that, it's very probable that that plugin exist, anyway, if you can't find any, you can use this code

```
`const a_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("a")

for (let i = 0; i < a_tag.length; i++){
  const url = a_tag[i].innerHTML
a_tag[i].setAttribute("href", url)
}`
```

[Here you got an example](https://jsfiddle.net/queflojera/fcw9dg81/2/)

Comment: I like where you are going with this. The problem is that the URLs don't have the <a> tag to begin with. They are just plain text. What I want to do is add the link tag to them in the editor